# Importing Excel to SQL Server CE

Tags: sql, excel, import, sql-server-ce

I have a table in excel format (2007 but I can save as anything below that, naturally), and I have a SQL Server Compact Edition 3.5 SP1 Database table with corresponding columns. I simply want to populate the SQLCE table with the data from the excel file. The data consists of strings and integers only.

I tried [this utility](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlceviewer/) to no avail, I also tried this [SQL script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338776/creating-a-sql-table-from-a-xls-excel-file/343345#343345) but it won't work since `BULK INSERT` is not supported in SQL Server CE. I also found this [Microsoft tutorial](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321686) but I am basically clueless when it comes to SQL, providers and the like...

Thanks !

**Edit:** I came up with the following code (via [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15828/reading-excel-files-from-c))

```
        var fileName = string.Format("{0}\\DataValues.xls", Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
        var connectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; data source={0}; Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;", fileName);

        var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", connectionString);
        var ds = new DataSet();

        adapter.Fill(ds, "anyNameHere");

        DataTable dataTable = ds.Tables["anyNameHere"];

        foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
            _entities.MyObjectSet.AddObject(new MyObject()
            {
                Foo= (string)row[1],
                Bar= Convert.ToInt32(row[2]),
            });

        _entities.SaveChanges();
```

But SaveChanges() crashes with "Server-generated keys and server-generated values are not supported by SQL Server Compact". I tried the [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/648449/server-generated-keys-and-server-generated-values-are-not-supported-by-sql-server/648507#648507) of changing all Id types to GUID(=uniqueidentifier) but I still get the message

**EDIT2:** I changed the StoreGeneratedPattern property to "None" and now it works. An interesting thing to note is that the `.SDF` file is copied to the runtime directory, and it is that *copy* that is altered, so you won't see the changes in the `.SDF` linked in your project - you'll have to copy it manually

My question still remains - is there a SQL Server CE equivalent to the following ?

```
BULK 
INSERT YourDestinationTable
        FROM 'D:\YourFile.csv'
            WITH
    (
                FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
                ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
    )
GO
```

Or even better - something like Microsoft's SQL Server Import and Export Wizard that can export to SQL Server CE?

Comment: Why not write a simple C# program that will use Office interop to read Excel file and SQLCE driver for writing to database? I am not providing an example since I do not remember Office interop by heart...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would avoid using the EF (at least for this).

You haven't posted your database schema, but have a look at [this](http://blog.stpworks.com/archive/2008/05/30/ado.net-entity-framework-sqlce-and-identity-columns.aspx) and [this](http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/a-few-sql-server-ce-and-entity-framework-gotchas/).

Although [EF supports it in general, CE does not](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc835494.aspx), so you will need to un-mark it as server-assigned and assign it when the object is created.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I ended up doing, i.e. switched my ID columns to StoreGeneratedPattern=None