# How to create SQL Server Table from ExcelSheet in asp c# .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, excel-2010

I have used below procedure code but its throwing an error:

Code:

```
SELECT * into TestTable FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0','Excel 8.0;Database=D:\ExamCenter.xls;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;', 'SELECT * FROM [user$]')
```

error:

> OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" for linked server "(null)" returned message "Unspecified error".
>       Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>       Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" for linked server "(null)".

Comment: can you share the actual code you are running?

Comment: read this article I hope it is helpful for you.
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338776/creating-a-sql-table-from-a-xls-excel-file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338776/creating-a-sql-table-from-a-xls-excel-file)

Comment: i have to create table based on excelsheet data structure, means columns of table decided based on excelsheet data.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following link to find an example

[Import Export example](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Read-and-Import-Excel-Sheet-into-SQL-Server-Database-in-ASP.Net.aspx)

Comment: i know these thing, my concern is i have excel with data and based on that data at run time create a table based on excel sheet data structure and import data.